# python - QWebView.setHtml doesn't load CSS files

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, pyqt5

I have a problem running a QWebView using a HTML file which contains CSS and JS files.

I'm running pyqt5 with Python 3.4 on windows 7 x64.

For example here is my HTML file test.html :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>A Sample Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
        <hr/>
        I have nothing to say.
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm calling my QWebView with HTML using line

```
view.setHtml(open("test.html").read())
```

Using only this code I can't get stylesheet and script running in the QWebView.
I found a solution for the CSS and JS files using line command :

```
view.settings().setUserStyleSheetUrl(QUrl.fromLocalFile("style.css"))
```

and for JS :

```
view.page().mainFrame().evaluateJavaScript(str(open("script.js").read()))
```

However I couldn't find a solution for fonts or images INSIDE css (or HTML) file. For example in styles.css :

```
src:url('fonts/times/timesroman.eot');
```

I tried absolute path but still not work.
Anyone can help ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution after 5hours searching, I had to use the prefix file:/// before setting the absolute path so my example will be :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>A Sample Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file:///C:/Users/....../style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///C:/Users/....../script.js">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
        <hr/>
        I have nothing to say.
    </body>
</html>
```

I hope this can help.